# Do all cuspidal automorphic representations of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$ come from Maass or holomorphic cusp forms?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, langlands-program

A normalized cuspidal newform $f$ (either holomorphic or Maass) can be identified with a function on $\phi: \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Q) \backslash \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$, and it generates an irreducible cuspidal automorphic representation in some $L^2$-space.  The central character of the corresponding representation depends on the some choice made in the transfer from $f$ to $\phi$.

Do these representations exhaust the cuspidal spectrum of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$?

Comment: Yes. This is probably buried somewhere in Gelbart, or Bump, or Goldfeld-Hundley (though I don't know where off the top of my head).

Comment: Note that this bijection only includes Maass forms of weight zero or one, and that weight one Maass forms with Laplacian eigenvalue $1/4$ are also holomorphic (their archimedean component is a limit of discrete series, namely the principal series $\mathrm{sgn} \boxplus 1$).

Comment: One can also define Maass forms of arbitrary integral weight (see e.g. Chapter 3 of Goldfeld-Hundley), and that one can map these to other Maass forms of different weights via raising and lowering operators. The point is that these are only newforms *in the archimedean aspect* if the weight is $0$, $1$, or an integer $\geq 2$ and additionally in the latter case that the form corresponds to a holomorphic cusp form. (You saw me give a talk about this in Pittsburgh.)

Comment: Hello @PeterHumphries , I think you are talking about Theorem 5.19 from the book by Gelbart (Automorphic forms on Adele group). This theorem says that there is a one to one correspondence between newforms and cuspidal automorphic representations of ${\mathrm{GL}}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$. I do not understand how Maass forms are coming into the picture. What am I missing here?

Comment: @user15243 By newform, they mean either a holomorphic newform or a Maass newform.